# app configuration appId is missing from Firebase Hosting reserved URL "/__/firebase/init.js" on localhost only

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I recently started seeing an error on my localhost version of Firebase hosted website in Chrome:

`Uncaught FirebaseError: Installations: Missing App configuration value: "appId" (installations/missing-app-config-values).`

I'm not sure what has triggered this. I'm using the Firebase Hosting Reserved URL method to include the firebase config and it's had no issues until recently.

The config is loaded via `<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>`.

This is the config file at that URL:

```
if (typeof firebase === 'undefined') throw new Error('hosting/init-error: Firebase SDK not detected. You must include it before /__/firebase/init.js');
var firebaseConfig = {
  "projectId": "remotesoc...",
  "databaseURL": "https://remotesoc...firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "remotesoc...appspot.com",
  "locationId": "us-central",
  "apiKey": "AIzaSyC3K7HT9- ... ",
  "authDomain": "remotesoc...firebaseapp.com",
  "messagingSenderId": "43697..."
};
if (firebaseConfig) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

As you can see the "appId" value is missing. I'm almost certain this used to be there.

I've built and deployed the app multiple times which is listed as the way to ensure that Firebase has the correct config values for the project.

The app is definitely using the correct project, and has a reference to the hosting site in the firebase.json

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "site": "remotesoc...",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

I've run `>firebase init` several times in an attempt to reset the CLI.

The deployed site has no missing config vars and is working perfectly this is only on localhost.

I could revert to using an included config file, however that negates the benefits of having the reserved URLs inject the values for you.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the app locally?

Comment: Hey @abraham I'm using this startup script config:
    "start": "run-p --race start:firebase start:react",
    "start:firebase": "firebase serve -p 4000",
    "start:react": "react-scripts start"

Comment: It looks like you're starting two dev servers and then loading the React served version. If you want to use `firebase serve` you'll have to build with CRA and then serve that built version.